# Showing Excel.Application VBA with intellisence in Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, reference, intellisense

I want to open an Excel file on my desktop and do some formatting changes to the headers.

When I try to declare objects the intellisense for Excel.Application is not showing up. I think this means my code won't work.

```vb
Sub OpenReviewFile()
   'Opens the reviewed file and formats the headers

    Dim objExcel As Excel.Application '<= when I type in this line of 
    code the intellisence doesn't work
    ...
```

I selected Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library in my References.
I checked my Options in Access and see nothing that might cause this.

I wrote more code and tried to run:

```vb
'Opens the reviewed file and formats the headers

Sub OpenReviewFile()
    'Opens the reviewed file and formats the headers

    Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim objbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objsheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim objRange As Excel.Range
    Dim intCol As Integer

    'Open Excel, Open the Reviewed file, Go to the Sheet in the excel 
    file

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objbook = 

    objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\cash10\Desktop\IBC_RECS_VS_HPMS.xlsx")
    Set objsheet = objbook.Worksheets("EXPORT_TABLE")

    For intCol = 1 To 11
        Set objRange = objsheet.Cell(1, intCol)
        Debug.Print objRange.Value
    Next
    ...
End Sub
```

I get Compile error:

> User-defined type not defined

Comment: `Set objRange = objsheet.Cells(1, intCol)`

Comment: Add a reference to the `Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library` (note **Excel**). After you add this reference, you can create a reference to a new Excel Application object with `Set objExcel = New Excel.Application` (early binding). When you don't set the reference, then you need to use `CreateObject` and then you don't have IntelliSense and you handle things quite differently (late binding).

Comment: Just add the right library as VBasic2008 stated and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

### Processing an Excel File From Access (Early Binding)

- You need to create a reference to `Tools->References->Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library` to run the following code.
- This should get you on your feet. Focus on the area I marked with `Playground`. Never mind if you don't understand all the code before and after.
- The basic idea is to open a new instance of Excel and then 'play in the playground' (do your thing) and finally close the workbook and quit the instance of Excel.
- Read the comments to see what to do if you want to keep Excel open.
- Due to the error-handling routine, errors will not be raised but their number and description will appear in the Immediate window (Ctrl+G).

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub OpenReviewFile()
    
    Const ProcName As String = "OpenReviewFile"
    
    ' Use a boolean to see if it was successful!
    Dim IsSuccess As Boolean
    
    ' Start an error-handling routine.
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    ' Either:
    ' Reference a new instance of Excel.
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application: Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    
    ' Or:
    ' Reference an existing instance of Excel.
    'Dim xlApp As Excel.Application: Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    ' Out-comment the line 'If Not xlApp Is Nothing Then xlApp.Quit'
    ' so it stays open!
    
    xlApp.Visible = True ' out-comment when done testing
        
'''''''''''
' The Playground
        
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open( _
        "C:\Users\cash10\Desktop\IBC_RECS_VS_HPMS.xlsx")
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("EXPORT_TABLE")
    
    Dim cell As Range, Col As Long

    For Col = 1 To 11
       Set cell = ws.Cells(1, Col)
       Debug.Print cell.Value
    Next Col
    
''''''''''
    
    IsSuccess = True
    
ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent endless loop
        ' Close the workbook without saving (when just reading).
        If Not wb Is Nothing Then wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        ' Quit the instance of Excel.
        If Not xlApp Is Nothing Then xlApp.Quit
        If IsSuccess Then
            MsgBox "Success.", vbInformation
        Else
            MsgBox "Something went wrong.", vbCritical
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
' Continue error-handling routine.
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

Comment: VBasic2008 Thank you so much for pointing out that I had added Office library instead of Excel library.  Jeeze,  I am so embarrassed to have missed it.  Your code above was also very helpful.  I really appreciate the help